# CHARINDEX AND THE DREADED..Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

[image: Please see the last line of code....I am able to parse out this person's name.]

The Trouble I am having is that when I cut and paste that last line into a new query tab it fails? Why does it work in one query tab then fail in the next? Same syntax.

[image: Copy pasted here fails....]

Comment: I have seen quite a few charindex error issues but not like this one. Thank you.

Comment: @Ala - You are right, I do NOT use employee number = 30 in the other tab...argh. It's part of a larger query of ALL employees.

Comment: @Ala - wait a second, how can I possibly have a negative number when I am subtracting a value that can only create a positive number? end_parameter will always be greater than start_parameter.

Comment: How about a record that doesn't have a comma ?. Then the end_parameter would be zero.

Comment: according to your question you are not copy paste same query in both tab you just edit your query in second tab you use the table in this case you just you need to use case Statement before substring `case when charInddex('=',manger)>1 then` your substring expression other wise manager field and any other static .

Comment: @Ala - the way the data is pulled from active directory, there will always be a comma there.

Comment: If the string is always comma separated, could you not try splitting down the string by the comma first, then retrieving the value from the split values. This could easily be achievable in a Table Valued Function.

Comment: @Arun Gairola - I implemented the "case when" statement as you recommended which worked. I saw that in many of the answers in other charindex related questions but I thought I had discovered a new problem. Thanks for everyone's input. appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesKSQL can you please vote up the Answer .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to your question you are not copy paste same query in both tab you just edit your query in second tab you use the table in this case you just you need to use case Statement before substring `case when charInddex('=',manger)>1 then` your substring expression other wise manager field and any other static